# Moving object on a curved path with Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, curve

I'm trying to move a div on a curved path, without any libraries or HTML5, just pure JavaScript.

The problem is how to calculate the coords (top left) of each step.

Does anyone have any idea?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? How is the curvature defined? Is it partial circle, elipse, hyperbole?